# Molecular rotation - Energy levels for an asymmetric molecule

Tags: rotational-dynamics, schroedinger-equation, rotation, molecular-dynamics

For a molecule with spherical symmetry, the energy level of rotation for quantum number $J$ is:

$$E(J)=\frac{J(J+1)\hbar^2}{8\pi^{2}I}$$

"$I$" is the Moment of inertia for the molecule ($I_{x}=I_{y}=I_{z}$ for a molecule with spherical symmetry)

For an asymmetric molecule however, $I_x$, $I_y$, $I_z$ are all different.  What would then be the expression for energy levels in terms of quantum numbers?  Thanks.

Comment: There is no general expression because the equations are too complicated to solve in general terms. A handful of special cases besides the spherically symmetric one are known to have simple expressions for their energy levels, but in general more complicated molecules require numerical approximations instead.

Comment: Take a look here http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/8/2/147.full.pdf+html and here http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/472731.pdf
maybe it helps.

Comment: I.N.Levine, Molecular Spectroscopy, p213, which also has a discussion about degeneracy.

Comment: Seems to be a fundamental confusion here.  What is a "molecule with spherical symmetry"?  No such thing.  Take a simple example: O2.  It has a definable moment of inertia about two axes only.  The third axis is along the line joining the atom, and a moment of inertia cannot be defined, but is in any case very small.  Please clarify what type of molecules you are thinking about.

Answer (score -1):

Download the file at https://www.dropbox.com/s/5l3lvqbal1ch2gm/Asymmetric%20Top.nb and run in Mathematica.

Executing the command en[3,0], for example, yields the energies and vector representations of the $J=3,m=0$ wavefunctions in the basis $$\{|3,-3,0\rangle,|3,-2,0\rangle,|3,-1,0\rangle,|3,0,0\rangle,|3,1,0\rangle,|3,2,0\rangle,|3,3,0\rangle\}$$ where the notation $|J,k,m\rangle$ is used. If you do not provide numerical values for $A_e,B_e,C_e$ then the code will attempt to yield exact analytic forms when it computes the eigensystem, which becomes impossible for $J>4$ or so and the program will stall. If you provide numerical values, it executes nearly instantly regardless of $J$. If you know your rotational constants, this can be used to find all the energy-levels quickly, or at least, the energy levels in the absence of rovibronic coupling.